# NSView Drawing & IsFlipped with overlayed image

Tags: objective-c, macos, drawing, nsview, drawrect

I've drawn onto an NSView which displays fine except for the fact it was flipped. I've set isFlipped to YES so it displays the correct way round.

I then overlay an image using drawInRect and [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

The problem is the overlayed image is now flipped incorrectly. How can I flip the main drawing but leave the overlayed image unflipped?

Comment: Is this about the (buggy) QR-code drawing code from the other questions?

Comment: so my answer to your earlier question

Comment: You cracked it thanks for your help Ol Sen :)

And Willeke no this is for something different - i'm playing around with drawing in general as i'm trying to learn - this is still very new to me so i'm trying to understand how everything works so I really appreciate everyones help I hope some day I will be as good of a coder as you guys :)

Answer (score 1):

You might try using `NSImage`'s [`drawInRect:fromRect:operation:fraction:respectFlipped:hints:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage/1520043-drawinrect?language=objc) method rather than `drawInRect:`:

```
[image drawInRect:rect
         fromRect:NSZeroRect
        operation:NSCompositeSourceOver
         fraction:1.0
   respectFlipped:NO
            hints:nil];
```

Passing `NO` for `respectFlipped:` may give you what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful to know unfortunately why it did flip the image it's Y positioning was reversed but Ol Sen helped me out :)

I'll give you an upvote still as this may come in handy to know down the line!